# Gulp watch for a handlebars project

Tags: javascript, gulp.js

I have project that uses handlebars and I'm using `gulp` and `gulp-compile-handlebars` to watch for changes in the handlebars template as well as the json structure used to compile the template.  I have implemented a watch which seems to work, but it feels like it's doing more work than it should.

My gulpfile looks like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var handlebars = require('gulp-compile-handlebars');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var batch = require('gulp-batch');
var argv = require('yargs').argv // for args parsing
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

handlebars.Handlebars.registerHelper('next', function(context, idx, options) {
    if (context[idx + 1]) {
        return options.fn(context[idx + 1])
    } else {
        return "";
    }
});


gulp.task('default', function () {
    var content = require('./content.js')
    var templateData = content
    options = {
        // partials : {
        //     footer : '<footer>the end</footer>'
        // },
        // batch : ['./src/partials'],
        // helpers : {
        //     capitals : function(str){
        //         return str.toUpperCase();
        //     }
        // }
    }

    return gulp.src(['index.handlebars'])
    .pipe(handlebars(templateData, options))
    .pipe(rename('indexCompiled.html'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});

// gulp.task('watch', function () {
//     watch('index.handlebars', batch(function (events, done) {
//         gulp.start('default', done);
//     }));
//     watch('content.js', batch(function (events, done) {
//         gulp.start('default', done);
//     }));
//     watch('gulpfile.js', batch(function (events, done) {
//         gulp.start('default', done);
//     }));
// });

gulp.task('auto-reload', function() {
    var p;

    gulp.watch('content.js', spawnChildren);
    gulp.watch('index.handlebars', spawnChildren);
    spawnChildren();

    function spawnChildren(e) {
        // kill previous spawned process
        if(p) { p.kill(); }

        // `spawn` a child `gulp` process linked to the parent `stdio`
        p = spawn('gulp', [argv.task], {stdio: 'inherit'});
    }
});
```

As I'm making changes I run `gulp auto-reload --task default` and any changes to the handlebars template or the json in `content.js` is re-compiled into `indexCompiles.html`.  Intially I was just trying to do a simple watch which you can see commented out in the gulp script.

```
// gulp.task('watch', function () {
//     watch('index.handlebars', batch(function (events, done) {
//         gulp.start('default', done);
//     }));
//     watch('content.js', batch(function (events, done) {
//         gulp.start('default', done);
//     }));
// });
```

That watch would run for all changes and recompile, but the only changes that were reflected in the new indexCompiled.html were the ones from `index.handlebars` any changes to the json in `content.js` was not reflected in the new compiled html I would have to stop the gulp watch and start it again, which is why I eventually made the `auto-restart` which works.  Why wasn't the original gulp watch working and is there a way to get it to work or do I need to use the `auto-restart` task?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood what you are doing correctly you are compiling `index.handlebars` using data from `content.js` and you want to recompile if any of those files changes. Below is a simplified and NOT TESTED example of what your code can look like

```
// removed gulp-watch (built in gulp by default)
// also removed spawn, argv and batch
var gulp = require('gulp');
var handlebars = require('gulp-compile-handlebars');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

handlebars.Handlebars.registerHelper('next', function(context, idx, options) {
    if (context[idx + 1]) {
        return options.fn(context[idx + 1])
    } else {
        return "";
    }
});

// compile index.handlebars with data from content.js
gulp.task('handlebars', function() {
    var templateData = require('./content.js');
    var options = {};

    return gulp.src(['index.handlebars'])
        .pipe(handlebars(templateData, options))
        .pipe(rename('indexCompiled.html'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});

// watch for changes in content and index files
// and then run handlebars task
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(['content.js', 'index.handlebars'], ['handlebars']);
});

// on run `gulp` compile and start watching for changes
gulp.task('default', ['handlebars', 'watch']);
```